# Solr Underlying core creation failed while creating collection

Tags: solr

**Underlying core creation failed while creating collection: workbrainJob**
I'm getting this error when trying to create a collection on Solr 8.9.0, Java 11

```
Collection: workbrainJob operation: create failed:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Underlying core creation failed while creating collection: workbrainJob
at org.apache.solr.cloud.api.collections.CreateCollectionCmd.call(CreateCollectionCmd.java:371)
at org.apache.solr.cloud.api.collections.OverseerCollectionMessageHandler.processMessage(OverseerCollectionMessageHandler.java:270)
at org.apache.solr.cloud.OverseerTaskProcessor$Runner.run(OverseerTaskProcessor.java:524)
at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:218)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Edited:
found the full error

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'workbrainJob_shard1_replica_n1': Unable to create core [workbrainJob_shard1_replica_n1] Caused by: The configset for this collection was uploaded without any authentication in place, and use of <lib> is not available for collections with untrusted configsets. To use this component, re-upload the configset after enabling authentication and authorization.
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:1358)
at
```

I was not planning to use the authentication plugin
Is it required to use the security in the new version of solr?

Comment: There should be a more specific error in the log on the node that attempted to create the core for the collection. This doesn't really say anything other than that core creation failed.

Answer (score 0):

This may vary depending on the version of Solr you are using, but [this](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_4/configsets-api.html) article says:

> This [API upload] functionality is enabled by default, but can be
> disabled via a runtime parameter `-Dconfigset.upload.enabled=false`.
> Disabling this feature is advisable if you want to expose Solr
> installation to untrusted users (even though you should never do
> that!).
>
> A configset is uploaded in a "trusted" mode if authentication is
> enabled and the upload operation is performed as an authenticated
> request. Without authentication, a configset is uploaded in an
> "untrusted" mode. Upon creation of a collection using an "untrusted"
> configset, the following functionality will not work:
>
> - If specified in the configset, the DataImportHandler’s ScriptTransformer will not initialize. The XSLT transformer (`tr` parameter) cannot be used at request processing time.
> - If specified in the configset, the StatelessScriptUpdateProcessor will not initialize.
> - Collections won’t initialize if  directives are used in the configset. (Note: Libraries added to Solr’s classpath don’t need the  directive)
>
> If you use any of these parameters or features, you must have enabled security features in your Solr installation and you must upload the configset as an authenticated user.

I haven't tested this, but it seems that you have 3 options:

- Update `-Dconfigset.upload.enabled=false` and try again
- Use the authentication plugin
- [Add the configset without the API](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_4/config-sets.html)